# "Airplay 2" to a Mac?

Tags: ios, imac, airplay, streaming

I have software (Reflector 2 and Airserver) that allow me to stream over AirPlay 1 from my iOS device.

However, AirPlay 1 does not allow me to use the multiple device feature built into AirPlay 2.

I can AirPlay 2 from my Mac to my HomePod and Apple TV and get all three devices playing the same stream. However, I can't control the music with my iOS device.

Is there a way I can play a stream to my Mac, AppleTV and Homepod from my phone?

Comment: OK, this can somewhat be done using the old "iTunes Remote" app that Apple makes.

1. Open app
2. Select shared library on the mac
3. Under "now playing", tap on the airplay icon in lower right
4. Select the Mac, and the other airplay devices

There are some drawbacks to this solution. The music is not in sync and there doesn't seem to be a way to stream music from Apple Music. You also can't control volume or change the song using the external phone controls. You have to use the iTunes Remote app.

Comment: Actually, the music is in sync. Make sure it is played to "Computer" and not through airplay software like Reflector 2.